# + (void)initialize and memory issues

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective-c and after having read some articles about good practices, it seems that the (void)initialize class method is the best place to initialize my global static variables :

```
static NSArray *tableCellBackgrounds = nil;

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [VariableDisplayViewController class])
    {
        tableCellBackgrounds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ListLine_Pair.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:40 topCapHeight:27],
            [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ListLine_Impair.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:40 topCapHeight:27],
            nil
        ];
        [tableCellBackgrounds retain];
    }
}
```

My problem now is: when/where should I send a 'release' message? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't :)

The memory of your app will get released anyway when closing the application so that is not an issue. There could be an issue however if in your singletons you open file handles which need to be closed on app shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with Joris that you don't need to release these.

Sometimes you allocate rather large static/global tables and data in `+(void)initialize` that serve all the instances of specific class, but when you release the last instance of that class, you would want to throw these resources away from memory, and not wait for the whole application process to shutdown.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any "`+(void)deinitialise`" in the ObjC NSObject methods, so the only technique I can suggest is that you also override the class methods

```
+ (instancetype)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use object initializers instead");
+ (instancetype)alloc OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use object initializers instead");
- (void)dealloc OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use 'deinit' to define a de-initializer");
```

and keep count of your class instances, adding 1 on 'alloc' and 'allocWithZone' and subtracting 1 on 'dealloc'.

Then, when your instance count goes to zero - go on and release those globals you allocated if you want.

Caution though: +(void)initialize won't be called again, when new instance will be created.

More Caution: thread safety should is also important here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with Joris that you don't need to release these.

Your question hints that resources you load as static/global in `+(void)deinitialise` are for internal use by all the instances of a specific class.

Such resources may have large memory footprint (data blocks needed for special algorithms, tables of constant data, images etc.

When the last instance of this class is released - it makes sense to release the global "class" data, and only load them again when new instances of the class are created.

Obviously, you don't want to wait for the whole application process to shutdown.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any "`+(void)deinitialise`" in the ObjC NSObject methods, so the technique I can suggest is that you manage this manually.

For that, you need also override the class methods

```
+ (instancetype)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use object initializers instead");
+ (instancetype)alloc OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use object initializers instead");
- (void)dealloc OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("use 'deinit' to define a de-initializer");
```

to keep count of your class instances, adding 1 on 'alloc' and 'allocWithZone' and subtracting 1 on 'dealloc'. (of course call super first).

Then, when your instance count goes to zero - go on and release those globals you allocated if you want.

You can also forget about `+(void)initialize` and load/initialize your resources when the first instance is created.

A word of Caution: thread safety should is also important here.